# O que há de errado no meu código JavaScript de scroll da tag body?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, rolamento, body

Olhem meu código pessoal, meu scroll está na tag body, mas ele não funciona, já fiz de tudo e nada o scroll meu ta na < body > e mesmo assim não funciona, o que há de errado ?

```
$(document.body).on("scroll", function(){
if($(document.body).scrollTop() > 10){
    $("#navbar").removeClass("fixed-bottom");
    $("#navbar").addClass("sticky-top");
    }else{
$("#navbar").removeClass("sticky-top");
    $("#navbar").addClass("fixed-bottom");
}});
```

Comment: Troque `document.body` por `window`.

Comment: Opa Sam, tudo bom ? Então troquei document.body por document.window e mesmo assim não funcionou, troquei document também só por window e nada. Dá uma olhada na página que estou mexendo: http://nexo.atspace.cc/Final . Nada do que eu faço funciona :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quem faz o scroll da página é o objeto `window`, e não o `body`, a não ser que você tenha colocado um overflow no body com altura definida.

Seu código correto seria:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
   $("span").html("Scroll: "+$(this).scrollTop()); // só para ilustrar. Apague esta linha
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 10){
      $("#navbar").removeClass("fixed-bottom");
      $("#navbar").addClass("sticky-top");
   }else{
      $("#navbar").removeClass("sticky-top");
      $("#navbar").addClass("fixed-bottom");
   }
});
```

```css
div{
   height: 2000px;
}

span{
   position: fixed;
   top: 10px;
   right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Role pra baixo</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Entendi Sam, não sei pq está dando isso, salvei testei na pagina e é como se o código não estivesse lá, era pra ele mudar a navbar do bottom para top, mas não funciona, mesmo com as mudanças realizadas, mas no meu css tem o seguinte style --> html{
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

Comment: Será que é aí que mora meu problema ? Eu acho que não porque quando eu coloca uma function e um onscroll na tag html nao funciona, mas na tag body funciona, não sei o porque

Comment: Já tentou `$("body")`?

Comment: Tentei não funcionou, vou acabar desistindo e perdendo, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado Sam, você manda bem demais!

Comment: Deu certo as coisas aqui, muito obrigado Sam